# Word and vowel count in VB 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, word-count

I need to program a simple console application that takes an input string and then calls a sub routine to figure out the amount of words and the amount of vowels in the string. I've written this and for some reason it doesn't output the text I put in the `Console.Writeline` code. Any help on how to do this?

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Sentence As String
        Console.WriteLine("Sentence Analysis")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence then press 'Enter'")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Sentence = Console.ReadLine()
        Sentence = Sentence.ToUpper
        Call Words(Sentence)
        Call Vowels(Sentence)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub Words(ByVal Input As String)
        Dim Count As Integer
        Dim Index As Short
        Dim Character As Char
        Do Until Index = Len(Input)
            Character = Input.Substring(Index)
            If Character = " " Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine("Your sentence contains {0} words.", (Count))
    End Sub

    Sub Vowels(ByVal Input As String)
        Dim Count As Integer
        Dim Vowels() As String = {"A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}
        Dim Index As Short
        Dim Character As Char
        Do Until Index = Len(Input)
            Character = Input.Substring(Index)
            If Character = Vowels(Index) Then
                Count = +1
            End If
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine("Your sentence contains {0} words.", (Count))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: In addition to A Friend's answer, you have a typo in the `Vowels` method: `Count = +1` - this will always make `Count = 1`. To increment it either do `Count = Count + 1` or `Count += 1`.

Comment: Also, `Vowels(Index)` will go out of bounds when `Index` is greater than 4. Use [**`Array.IndexOf()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) instead or add another loop iterating every vowel inside your `Do` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Words` you have the following code:

`Do Until Index = Len(Input)`

Index is never incremented and so loops infinitely.

Same issue in `Vowels` as well

Answer (score 0):

Is the following any help to you?

Rather than looking at whether a sentence contains vowels, it looks at whether a list of vowels contains each character in the sentence.

For the word count, it similarly asks whether a string containing a single space contains each character in the sentence (the "word count" in this case is just a count of spaces, so leading or trailing spaces, or extra spaces between words, will be counted as extra words, as your code currently does).

It also allows us to abolish the separate method calls, and the hand-rolled looping code which, as you can see, are prone to small bugs (and I personally would recommend using a `For` loop rather than `Do Until` loop in this kind of situation, because `For` loops are designed to increment the index automatically).

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Sentence Analysis")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence then press 'Enter'")
    Console.WriteLine()

    Dim sentence As String
    sentence = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim vowel_count As Integer = sentence.Count(Function(c) "aeiou".Contains(Char.ToLower(c)))
    Dim word_count As Integer = sentence.Count(Function(c) " ".Contains(Char.ToLower(c)))

    Console.WriteLine("Your sentence contains {0} words.", word_count)
    Console.WriteLine("Your sentence contains {0} vowels.", vowel_count)        

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You go to the same college as I did. Here is the code...

```
Option Compare Text
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics.Metrics
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Program
Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("Sentence Analysis")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence, then press 'Enter'")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine
    Dim letterbyletter() As Char = input.ToCharArray
    Dim counter As Integer = 1
    Dim vowelcounter As Integer
    Call wordcount(input, letterbyletter, counter)
    Console.WriteLine("Your sentence contains {0} words.", counter)
    Call vowelcount(input, letterbyletter, vowelcounter)
    Console.WriteLine("Your sentence contains {0} vowels.", vowelcounter)
End Sub
Sub wordcount(ByVal input As String, ByRef letterbyletter() As Char, ByRef 
    counter As Integer)
    For i = 0 To Len(input) - 1
        If letterbyletter(i) = " " Then
            counter += 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub vowelcount(ByVal input As String, ByRef letterbyletter() As Char, ByRef 
    vowelcounter As Integer)
    Dim vowels() As String = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}
    For i = 0 To Len(input) - 1
        For j = 0 To 4
            If letterbyletter(i) = vowels(j) Then
                vowelcounter += 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    End Sub
    End Module
```